# Convert hex to binary in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, binary, hex

Currently I search a function in MySQL to do conversion between hex string to binary representation, example:

```
0000 -> 0000000000000000
00AA -> 0000000010101010
FFFF -> 1111111111111111
```

I have already tried

```
UNHEX('00AA')
CAST('00AA' AS BINARY)
CONVERT('00AA', BINARY)
```

but didn't get the results I want.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `CONV()` function:

```
CONV(string, 16, 2)
```

To have length according to input:

```
LPAD(CONV(string, 16, 2), LENGTH(string)*4, '0')
```

As `CONV()` works with 64-bit precision, you can't have more than 64 bits converted, so you can use this as well:

```
LPAD(CONV(string, 16, 2), 64, '0')
```

and you should check that `LENGTH(string) <= 16` or you may get erroneous results.

Comment: thanks, can it always displayed as 16-digit, tried 00AA -> 10101010, can it display 0000000010101010

Comment: This is incorrect. CONV() converts integers, not strings. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv

Comment: @utdrmac yet it does the work. I did not claim that the function does not convert integers. That's exactly what it does.

Answer (score 24):

```
UNHEX('hex string')
```

Would interpret each pair of characters in a string passed into the function as two hex characters and try to convert that to a binary number (binary format in mysql). This way, you can convert a string to binary. However, this won't display the content as a string of binary digits. Rather, each 2 bytes in the resulting string converted to the specific character encoding (for example utf8).

Comment: @ekscrypto, explaining why the OP cannot see the result he expected by using UNHEX, although it is doing what he is actually expecting it to do.