# Convert HEX column to DEC in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, hex, decimal, typeconverter

I am writing an application which will do some formatting to CSV file and uploads the table to mysql after that the program should convert a (hex) column to decimal one

The table looks like this:

col1 | col2 | hexcol | deccol

So i need to take hexcol and convert from hex2dec and put it into deccol

I tried simple **SELECT UNHEX('hexcol');**   but it won`t work it says this colum is not in the field list ...

Any help would be appreciated ...

Comment: SELECT UNHEX(hexcol) FROM table; no quotes, because that treats the value as a string, not as a column name

Comment: I dont know why but when i add FROM table ... it works ... how can i update deccol now with UNHEX(hexcol) ... i tried update table set deccol = UNHEX(hexcol) but it doesnt affect any row ... ???

Comment: What datatype is your deccol column?

Comment: 0 rows affected. ( Query took 0.0131 sec ) eventhough there are more then thousand rows ...

Comment: i meant deccol column data type is varchar(40)

Comment: SELECT UNHEX(hexcol) FROM table ... gets all hexcol datas but the same as they are ... it is not unhexing ... could anyone tell me what datatypes should they be?

Answer (score 29):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONV(hexcol, 16, 10);
```

Comment: When i try SELECT CONV(hexcol, 16, 10); i got #1054 - Unknown column 'hexcol' in 'field list'

Comment: Only this one (SELECT CONV(  '`hexcol`', 16, 10 )) works but it takes hexcol as a string

Comment: This one worked ... i dont know why Mysql takes some spaces when using columns ... !!!

Answer (score 4):

You can use CONV()

Check [Similar question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699424/convert-hex-to-binary-in-mysql) and 
[Conv function reference & examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv)