# MySQL convert BLOB content to signed integer

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, how to convert HEX to SIGNED i.e. FF to -1?

I've tried CONVERT('FF', SIGNED) but it returns 0.

Comment: did you find a solution? having the same problem here ...

Answer (score 1):

Its `CONV` not `CONVERT`.

Just an example

```
CONV(string, 16, 2)
```

Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699424/convert-hex-to-binary-in-mysql)

Comment: I think CONV(string, 16, 2) will give the binary representation (zeros and ones). I would like to have the signed int. May be I'm missing some thing?

Comment: Then you want CONV(string, 16, 10). The second number is the base. 2 converts to binary, 10, to decimal.